# Inbound Email Activity History

Tags: apex-email-service

Is there a way to have inbound emails on the Activity History? We want to see inbound emails on the Activity history in lightning. There is the email related list but we want all the inbound outbound emails on the Activity History.

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352468&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1) this is working as designed, To track the email thread for outbound and inbound emails for a case record you need to add the email related list on case layout.  The case feed actually shows all the emails regardless if it is an outbound or inbound email.

Also, outbound emails are stored in Activity History Related List, Inbound emails are stored in the Email related list. Case feed then shows both of emails from 'Activity History' and 'Email Related Lists'.

Thanks